# Custom function in Puppet 4.10 only returning first array item in hash

Tags: ruby, puppet

A custom function in Puppet that reads SSL certificates from a database, returns it's results as an array of hashes. This function is used to keep SSL certificates up to date on our proxy servers.

When creating a proxy vhost, we read the SSL certificate to determine for which hosts the vhost should be active. We do this by retrieving the "subject alternative names" from the certificate and parsing them into an array.

The following code extracts the SANs:

```
def subject_alt_names
  san = @x509.extensions.find { |e| e.oid == 'subjectAltName' }
  san.value.split(',').map { |name| name.strip.sub!('DNS:', '') }
end
```

The `@x509` variable contains an instance of `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new` and the `subject_alt_names` produces the expected array of names that are in the certificate.

So far so good!

Now, when collecting all the certificates, we create an array of hashes based on the results we retrieved from the database.

The code looks similar to:

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'certificates') do
  dispatch :up do
  end

  def up
    # Omitted DB calls

    mappings.map { |mapping|
      certificate = Certificate.new(
        OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(mapping['certificate']),
        OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(mapping['private_key']),
        mapping['intermediates']
      )

      {
        'common_name' => certificate.common_name,
        'domains' => certificate.subject_alt_names,
        'private_key' => certificate.private_key,
        'certificate' => certificate.x509,
        'intermediates' => certificate.chain
      }
    }
  end
end
```

When calling the function in Puppet, the `domains` array in the hash only contains one entry ("domain.tld") instead of two ("domain.tld" and "www.domain.tld"). Most SSL certificates in the database contain two SAN names.

A really simple test function produces the result that we expect:

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'certificates_test') do
  dispatch :up do
  end

  def up
    test = "DNS:domain.tld, DNS:www.domain.tld, DNS: www2.domain.tld"

    domains = test.split(',').map { |name| name.strip.sub!('DNS:', '') }

    {
      'domains' => domains
    }
  end
end
```

Output:

```
{
    "domains" => ["domain.tld", "www.domain.tld"]
}
```

When executing the code in Puppet, only the first entry in the "domains" array is returned. The function is called in Puppet in a way similar as below:

```
certificates().each |$certificate| {
    $domains = $certificate['domains']

    # Omitted defining of hosts based on $certificate
}
```

Running on Puppet 4.10.12 (server 2.8.1) on CentOS.

Output of `facter rubysitedir rubyversion`:

```
rubysitedir => /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
rubyversion => 2.1.9
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what your current state is in terms of what kind of output you are getting and what you want to achieve. Please modify the question to give details on what the current situation is and what you are trying to achieve. However, I can tell you that your lambda iterator will have an error once you fix the `certificates` function because you will be attempting to modify the immutable variable `$domains` on each iteration. I can help you fix that too once you edit your question.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your response. I've updated my question according to your comment, I hope it's clear that we expect to see all of the SAN names of the certificate (instead of just the first). There is no error because the variable is declared within the scope of "each".

Comment: There is a lot of code and explanation missing here, but based on what you write all I can conclude is the line `'domains' => certificate.subject_alt_names` only returns one name, which means `certificate.subject_alt_names` only returns one name, which means the statement "So far so good" must be false. Where else could the problem be otherwise?

Comment: Well, that's the question: the `certificate.subject_alt_names` returns all the names that are in the certificate, but when the code is run on an agent, it only returns the first name. My guess is that Puppet runs some modified version of Ruby or I'm completely missing something. I've created a demo that "proves" the "subject_alt_names" method will return the expected result: https://repl.it/repls/WickedFearfulAlgorithm

Comment: Ok, right. Then we're on the same page. The problem must be in OpenSSL::X509::Certificate, because you say @x509 is an instance of that class. Therefore the problem can't really be anywhere else. I.e. step 1: narrow down the scope of your problem. This was my initial hunch also that there is a patch somewhere in Puppet for this behavior.

Comment: Good idea, I will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check what Ruby version you're running on the agent `ruby -v`? I tried your sample with everything from 1.8 to 2.5. Can't reproduce the problem with these standard Ruby versions. Other possibility is some sort of OpenSSL issue.

Comment: With the new information provided in the question, I would agree the problem stems from the `OpenSSL` class usage now that I understand what the use of `certificates_test` is proving as a control variable. If `subject_alt_names` is returning an array of names from the certs, then why reinstantiate the object within the mapping in the second block of code? Is that method not usable directly for your desired functionality? I am probably missing something here about the intent of your array to hash method.

Comment: As for the the immutability issue, I misinterpreted the purpose of that variable and thought you wanted it to aggregate outside the lambda scope at the class scope. You are totally correct about that code being fine.

Comment: @Casper I've included the output of the `facter rubysitedir rubyversion` command in my question, which gives the same output on both the Puppet master and agent servers. @Matt Updated my question so that the second code block is a bit more clear: the output of the method needs to be something Puppet can understand, this was the easiest solution I could come up with.

Comment: Can you run `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` on the agent.

Comment: Ruby is not installed on the agent. The code is running on the Puppet server, using JRuby. I'm trying to update the OpenSSL version there (gem called "jruby-openssl") but so far I've only managed to break more than solve anything...

Comment: Hehe. Sounds like fun :) But I think you are on the right track. Updating OpenSSL is worth a shot.

Comment: Not really that much fun ;-) upgrading the package breaks a lot of dependencies... But I'll get there. Just stumbled upon a fun fact going through the history of the "jruby-openssl" gem... version 0.9.18 contained an update for SAN: "simple resolution for handling subjectAltName multiple DNS: names". So, if I could just get that version working.... all problems will disappear :)

Comment: Since Puppet functions are run by the catalog compiler and not by the agent, it's unclear what code it is that you say only returns the first name on the agent.  You've in fact not presented *anything* that would be conveyed to the agent.

Comment: @John I don't fully understand what you mean. In the last code block you can see the custom `certificates` function being called, which is in a manifest that is applied to the agent. The code that is not returning all of the SSL certificate SAN names is `certificate.subject_alt_names` (a call of the method `subject_alt_names` on `certificate` which is an instance of a Certificate class I wrote).

Comment: @TEDx, I see you've solved your problem, so congratulations!  With respect to your comment, however, you have a misunderstanding: Puppet never applies *any* manifest to the target node.  Instead, it uses manifests to inform how to construct a *catalog* of classes and resources that are applied to the node.  You have not presented anything that shows how the results of your function call affect the contents of the catalog in any way.

Comment: @John thanks! And you are absolutely right, of course. I was really focussed on the issue of the custom `certificates` function and left out essential information on how it is used, and skipped essential parts of the Puppet process. I've updated my question (still left out the actual code though) to give more information on how the function is used: the `$certificates` array produces input when constructing the catalog in order to create `nginx::resource::server` resources on a server running Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by updating the "subject_alt_names" method of the Certificate class. I think Puppet sometimes makes it difficult to develop extensions, because of the fact that custom functions are executed using JRuby (which has its differences). In this case, the OpenSSL extension that I was using doesn't return all the SAN names in one string, instead it splits it up and makes it an array of hashes.

The following code works with the OpenSSL extension of both JRuby and Ruby (where the `x509` argument is an instance of `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate`):

```
def subject_alt_names x509
  names = []

  x509.extensions.each do |e|
    next if e.oid != 'subjectAltName'

    names << e.value.split(',').map { |name|
      name.strip.sub!('DNS:', '')
    }
  end

  names
end
```

Thanks for all of the comments! It really helped me figuring this out :)